# How to add numbers in their thousands into a FLOAT data type - FIXED

Tags: mysql

I've been trying to figure out a way to add currency into a database. The best way i came across (in mysql) was to have a float data type.

My float data type is:

```
outstandanding_amount FLOAT (8, 2);
```

When i want to add something to that variable, it works fine. Let's say I want to add $675.75 into the database, it puts it in and it looks like this:

```
| outstanding_amount |
              675.75
```

This is perfectly fine. However when i want to add let's say $2,000.00, it adds it into the database and in the database it looks like this:

```
| outstanding_amount |
                2.00
```

I'm not sure why it's doing this, i've tried increasing the 8 in FLOAT (8, 2) to 20, so it looks like FLOAT (20, 2). But that didn't work

Comment: problem in regional settings. In some countries decimal separator is . and in some is ,

Comment: ah thanks, i fixed it so that it tries to add the 1,000 as 1000 rather than 1,000. Cheers :D